# Update the remote of a git branch after name changing

Tags: git, version-control

Consider the following situation. A remote repository has two branches `master` and `b1`. In addition it has two clones `repo1` and `repo2` and both have `b1` checked out. At some point, in `repo1` the name of `b1` was changed. As far as I can tell, the following is the right procedure to change the name of `b1`:

```
$ git branch b1 b2 # changes the name of b1 to b2
$ git push remote :b1 # delete b1 remotely
$ git push --set-upstream origin b2 # create b2 remotely and direct the local branch to track the remote 1
```

Now, afterwards, in `repo2` I face a problem. `git pull` doesn't pull the changes from the branch (which is now called remotely `b2`). The error returned is:

```
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'b1'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

What is the right way to do this? Both the renaming part and the updating in other clones?

Comment: It looks to me like you did the renaming part correctly, but there isn't any way of forcing branches to be renamed in other repos AFAIK. However, in `repo2` you could do `git pull; git checkout b2` to switch to the new branch.

Comment: So you say that in `repo2` I should manually (and locally) delete `b1` and checkout `b2` after a `git fetch`?

Comment: Yes, I think that is what you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the remote upstream branch that your current branch is configured to pull from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879224/637283

This may cause issues though, fully understand that post before you do it.

Comment: I figure probably because I didn't put any explanation in my answer and just linked to another.